# Add multiples of rows till they satisfy an arbitrary sum then return the rows that do

Tags: mysql

Am not sure if this is possible. Let's say I have an arbitrary figure like 200, I have a table with two columns (both ints). Lets call the columns `col_a` and `col_b`.

I need to perform one query such that if `col_a * col_b` for the first row does not equal to my arbitrary figure (in this case `200`), keep whatever value the first row equates to and go to second row, do the same while adding the results to the value we got from the first row, repeat this till the total equates to our arbitrary value.

In an example. Lets use our arbitrary figure of 200 say we have `row 1 (col_a*colb) = 20`, `row 2 (col_a*col_b) = 70`, `row 3 (col_a*colb) = 110`, `row 4 (col_a*col_b) = 30`.

My query should return row 1, row 2 and row 3. How is this possible in sql? I am using mysql.

Comment: If you are using MySQL, then why did you add the PostgreSQL tag and the Oracle PL/SQL tag?. This would be quite easy in Postgres and Oracle using [modern SQL](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2015-02/modern-sql) like window functions

Comment: I wanted to attract as many folks to view the questions, to enhance my chance of getting answers. I have edited the questions and removed the other tags following your comment :-) @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

You could use user defined variable in mysql to achieve your goal:

```
create table t ( id int not null auto_increment, 
                 col_a int not null, 
                 col_b int not null, 
                 primary key(id) );

insert into t(col_a, col_b) values (1,20), (1,70), (1,110), (1,30);

set @sum := 0;
select *, col_a * col_b, @sum as s 
from t
where (@sum := @sum + (col_a * col_b)) <= 200
order by id; 

+----+-------+-------+---------------+------+
| id | col_a | col_b | col_a * col_b | s    |
+----+-------+-------+---------------+------+
|  1 |     1 |    20 |            20 |   20 |
|  2 |     1 |    70 |            70 |   90 |
|  3 |     1 |   110 |           110 |  200 |
+----+-------+-------+---------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You must use `order by` to make sure of the rows order as suggested by ypercube. For example you can sum column in reverse order.

```
set @sum := 0;
select *, col_a * col_b, @sum as s  
from t where (@sum := @sum + (col_a * col_b)) <= 200 
order by id desc;

+----+-------+-------+---------------+------+
| id | col_a | col_b | col_a * col_b | s    |
+----+-------+-------+---------------+------+
|  4 |     1 |    30 |            30 |   30 |
|  3 |     1 |   110 |           110 |  140 |
+----+-------+-------+---------------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You should have an `order by` in the query. Otherwise, the result can vary from execution to execution.